# Launch Screen only showing once

Tags: ios, xcode

I have used the LaunchScreen.storyboard file in my swift file to create a launch screen, however I only see the launch screen when I load the app onto my phone. After that, even when I kill the app I don't see the launchscreen again. I want it so that it shows every time the app is booted, so after it's been removed from the background like most other apps that exist. I there a setting that i need to toggle, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It will be displayed each time your app is launched, but if your app has been run recently and/or is small then it will launch very quickly, resulting in a very brief appearance of the launch image. You may not see it at all.

Comment: is there any way of making it appear for longer like in other apps?

Comment: Yes, make your initial view controller in your main storyboard the same as your launch image and then segue to your current first scene after a delay

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be achieved from the initial ViewController instead of Launch Screen.

Reason: Launch Screen timing is not fixed and can have a very short appearance if the app has recently been in the memory.

I would recommend you to use the welcome graphic/animation on the initial View Controller and move to the intended View Controller after a set timer by using a segue.

Edit: Additionally, in case of a graphic, you can put that on the Launch screen as well, then on the initial View Controller. That will get you continuity.

Hope this helps.